# Is this MySQL query the best idea?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

The project I'm working on has two type of accounts, "`people`" and "`companies`".

I hold a single "`users`" table with all the accounts and just the basic info needed for login (email, pass, etc), and two other tables "`user_profiles`" (regular people) and "`company_profiles`" (companies) that hold more specific columns for each type, both of the tables linked to the general "`users`" table via a "`profile_user_id`" column.

But, whenever I want to list users that can be both people and companies, I use :

"`select user_id, user_type, concat_ws('', concat_ws(' ', user_profiles.profile_first_name, user_profiles.profile_last_name), company_profiles.profile_company_name) as user_fullname`".

When I list these users I know whether they're people or companies by the "`user_type`".

Is my approach using `concat_ws` the right (optimal) one? I did this instead of `select`-ing every `*_name` to avoid returning more columns than necessary.

Thanks

EDIT: the query above continues like: `from users left join user_profiles on ... left join company_profiles on ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
 u.user_id, u.user_type, concat_ws(profile_first_name + profile_last_name) as full_name
from 
 users u, user_profiles up
where u.key = up.key
 and u.user_type = 'user'

union

select
 u.user_id, u.user_type, concat_ws(profile_first_name + profile_last_name) as full_name
from 
 users u, company_profiles cp
where u.key = cp.key
 and u.user_type = 'company'
```

Comment: Considering that the two `profile` tables have disjoint sets of `users`, because a user can be either a `person` or a `company`, is the UNION solution better than my initial concat idea?

Comment: run an explain plan and see the difference

relational databases are meant for processing sets

Comment: Both queries end up doing 2 joins.  This one is more explicit and understandable, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Does the query you already have work? Is it that you're experiencing performance issues from using this approach already?

Unless using the above query is taking way longer than you're expecting it to be or is causing issues in the software calling this information, this might be pre-mature optimization.

One thing to note though, your first use of CONCAT_WS doesn't have a seperator, so the company name is going to be merged with the person's name.

Comment: The query I wrote above already works, I'm just questioning its optimality. 
The reason the first concat_ws doesn't have a separator is that I'm actually concating two columns one of which I *know* is NULL after left joining the users table to the user_profiles and company_profiles.

Comment: So if you're not expecting to have both user_profile AND company_profile information present for a single user entry to do something like "Stephen Colbert, Comedy Central" then MSON's query would be best.